# MVC 3 Layout and Controllers

Tags: layout, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-controller

I m building a MVC 3 applications. The application should be able to display a different layout according to the sub domaine (ex: customer1.mysite.com -> layout1; customer2.mysite.com -> layout2; etc...) it will have also a layout for mobile and IE 6.

I have seen that their is the _ViewStart.cshtml that I can leverage to do the logic to set the layout. But what I don't get is where is the controler for that? Should I write all the code in the view?

An other question with layout how to do you factor out the code for the common behaviours? Do you have a controler for that?

And a last one I have seen the concept of areas in asp.net MVC2 is it obsolete now that we have Razor?

Thank you for your help

Fred

Comment: BTW - your system is referred to as a multi-tenant system/architecture. There are some really good mvc related questions on this topic. Eg http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net-mvc+multi-tenant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could do this in the _ViewStart I think that a better way would be to write a [custom view engine](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx) in which based on the user agent or the domain include a different layout. Then you would have common controllers and views, only the layout will differ.

Comment: Thank you Darin, very interesting alternative.

I have seen that but without any sample. Do you know if someone has already tried?  
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx :
: "Important: Because the _ViewStart.cshtml allows us to write code, we can optionally make our Layout selection logic richer than just a basic property set.  For example: we could vary the Layout template that we use depending on what type of device is accessing the site – and have a phone or tablet optimized layout for those devices, and a desktop optimized layout for PCs/Laptops."

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a good time to use [ViewBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).

The idea is that during [OnActionExecuting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting.aspx), you would look up the subdomain and shove it into the ViewBag. This can be done in a custom BaseController from which your other controllers inherit, or from an [ActionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609.aspx).

Then, in your _ViewStart, you can write a switch statement on ViewBag to control layout.

For example, here is an ActionFilter that will populate `@ViewBag.Subdomain` in any of your Razor views, including _ViewStart.cshtml.

```
public class AddSubdomainToViewDataAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var subdomain = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority.Split('.').First();
        var controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
        controller.ViewData.Add("Subdomain", subdomain);
    }
}
```

Then, decorate your controllers with this new `[AddSubdomainToViewData]` attribute.

Finally, in _ViewStart.cshtml, do something like this:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/" + ((@ViewContext.ViewData["Subdomain"] as String) ?? String.Empty) + "_layout.cshtml";
}
```

This will use a different Razor layout for each subdomain.

Comment: Thank you Portman,
Would you suggest it's better to use action filter or to go directly like that :

Comment: sorry I pressed enter...

@{
    var subdomain = this.Context.Request.Url.Authority.Split('.').First();
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/" + ((@ViewContext.ViewData["Subdomain"] as String) ?? String.Empty) + "_layout.cshtml";
}
'

Comment: If you're *just* using the subdomain, then ignore the ActionFilter, and just use the HttpContext directly in your ViewStart. But I was guessing that you were going to use the subdomain to do a database lookup, in which case you should encapsulate in an ActionFilter.